# mysql varchar2 row overflow

Tags: mysql, varchar

i have a mysql 5.1.50 server.
i recently created a dump file for some old tables with data transformed from old versions of mysql.
during import, i got 'Data truncated for column' messages. short search showed that there are rows with varchar values that exceed the defined varchar value of the table.

1. how is that possible? tried to recreate it without success, has anyone encountered such state?
2. how can i find the problematic rows without full table scanning the entire db?
3. most important, can this be fixes (again, with a simple solution, complete drop-create wont help)

from db (data is obscured but real fetches):

```
desc xxx

+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| date           | date             | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| int1           | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| v1             | varchar(200)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| v2             | varchar(200)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| i2             | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| i3             | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| f1             | float            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| f2             | float            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

select count(id) from xxx where length(v1)>200 group by length(v1);

+-----------+------------------+
| count(id) | length(v1)       |
+-----------+------------------+
|         7 |              201 |
|         1 |              202 |
|         1 |              203 |
|         5 |              204 |
|         1 |              205 |
|         1 |              206 |
|         5 |              207 |
|         9 |              208 |
|         4 |              209 |
|         1 |              210 |
|        67 |              212 |
|        13 |              214 |
|         1 |              215 |
|         1 |              216 |
|         2 |              220 |
|         2 |              221 |
|         2 |              230 |
|         2 |              235 |
|         1 |              274 |
|         1 |              290 |
|         1 |              320 |
+-----------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your varchar fields to be bigger than 200 characters.

> Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to 65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions. The effective maximum length of a VARCHAR in MySQL 5.0.3 and later is subject to the maximum row size (65,535 bytes, which is shared among all columns) and the character set used.

Read more at the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/char.html)

What the above statement is saying is that you can define varchar columns with length bigger than 255, how long the sum of the sizes of all the varchar columns from that table is not bigger than  65,535
To be more specific you can modify your table columns:

```
ALTER TABLE xxx CHANGE v1 v1 VARCHAR(500);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems that at least some of the string values are multi-byte (`length()` returns size in bytes, `char_length()` - size in characters
2. `SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE LENGTH(v1) != CHAR_LENGTH(v1)`
3. Usually import/export script should take care of such things(assuming your destination server supports multi-byte characters). What tool do you use for export/import? As far as I know, mysqldump doesn't have such a problem.